# Set version number for Swift executable command line tool

Tags: swift, xcode, command-line, executable

I have built a small command line tool with an Xcode template.
The built works as it should, I can Archive it to obtain an executable quite fine.

What I cannot figure out is where I can set the version number of the binary. I do not have a `Info.plist`, but I can see several places containing the verb "Version"–none of which will attach a version number to my binary.

What am I missing here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line tools don't have *external* info like a version number (eg something that would show up in the Finder). You should write *internal* code that returns a version number when someone calls `SwiftyAppleMailCreator --version`.